# IIF() function not properly working while using in MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012, mdx-query

I need to get calculated measure values based on conditions.

Am having the below data in my cube
[image]

I have created below calculated measure using IIF() function

**IF([Title] = "Sales Representative",[Reseller Order Count],0)**

I have tried with below query:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS IIF([EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE  = "SALES REPRESENTATIVE",[Reseller Order Count],0) SELECT{
[Measures].[Expression1]} ON COLUMNS FROM [Sales Targets] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

It returns **0** but the value returned must be **3693**
[image]

But while using dimension field in the above query, it returns value for that particular Title and remaining Titles has 0.

```
WITH
         MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS IIF([EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE  = "SALES REPRESENTATIVE",[Reseller Order Count],0)    SELECT{
        [Measures].[Expression1]} ON COLUMNS ,NONEMPTY((TOPCOUNT(
        (Order((([Employee].[Title].[Title].ALLMEMBERS)),[Employee].[Title].CurrentMember.MemberValue,ASC)),101)),{
        [Measures].[Expression1]}) ON ROWS FROM [Sales Targets] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

[image]

Is there any way to get the result without using dimension field in the MDX query?

I have checked multiple solutions in StackOverFlow and tried but none has achieved my requirement.
Can anyone please guide me to get the required value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIF() function not working properly while using multiple times in single MDX query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822913/iif-function-not-working-properly-while-using-multiple-times-in-single-mdx-que)