# IIF() function not working properly while using multiple times in single MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012, mdx-query

I need to get the aggregated values based on two conditions using single MDX query

Am having below data
[image]

I have created two calculated functions using IIF() function in a below query

```
WITH
         MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS IIF([EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE  = "SALES REPRESENTATIVE",[Reseller Order Count],0)
         MEMBER [Measures].[Expression2] AS IIF([EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE  = "SALES REPRESENTATIVE",0,[Reseller Order Count])    SELECT{
        [Measures].[Expression1],
        [Measures].[Expression2]} ON COLUMNS FROM [Sales Targets] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

The output must be 3693 and 103 but it returned as below

[image]

Isthere any changes need to be done in query?

Can anyone please guide me to get the proper result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right idea but needed to perform this calculation across employee titles:

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Expression1] AS 
   SUM(
     [EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].[TITLE].MEMBERS,
     IIF([EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].CURRENTMEMBER IS [EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].[SALES REPRESENTATIVE],[Reseller Order Count],Null)
   )
  MEMBER [Measures].[Expression2] AS 
   SUM(
      [EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].[TITLE].MEMBERS,
      IIF([EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].CURRENTMEMBER IS [EMPLOYEE].[TITLE].[SALES REPRESENTATIVE],Null,[Reseller Order Count])    
    )
SELECT{
        [Measures].[Expression1],
        [Measures].[Expression2]} ON COLUMNS FROM [Sales Targets] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```